# Change to class file not reflected

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texniccenter

I am using a class file to help document my thesis. I need to make  some basic changes and I therefore go and edit my class file.

I save it and then in Texnic Center when I do <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> I do not get the updated information.

Is there another way to compile or something? I am not sure why changes do not get reflected.

Comment: What exactly is your "class" file? Is it a custom `.cls` file that you are using through `\documentclass`?

Comment: Why are you editing the style file directly rather than doing your modifications in the preamble to your document?

Comment: @Seamus : because I was asked to shift everything on my title page 1 in downward and my thesis tex file just has \maketitle command.If there is another way to do this I'd be more than glad to try.

Comment: @rty: You could use a `titlepage` environment. Furthermore, you could provide a link to the class file which would make it easier to help.

Comment: @Stefan : Here is the link to the website  https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/ECEThesisReview/LaTeX+Resources  .It is the first download on this page -uiucecethesis09.cls

Comment: I tried changing the .cls file and add space at the top but that shifts just the title down and everything else is pretty much where it is making it look very awkward.I also tried to add \vspace{10 mm} right before \maketitle but then there is no effect on the output page

Comment: If you let us see the `.cls` file and clearly describe your intent, you'll surely get a quick solution to your problem.

Comment: @Gonzalo :I did provide a link to the cls file above.My intent is just that all the text on the title page gets shifted down by an inch.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see it. Will look into it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying directly a `.cls` file is not a good practice. Instead you can make the modification(s) in your `.tex` file (redefining what you need, and using `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` if necessary). Another option is to use the `etoolbox` package; in this case, we only have to patch the `\maketitle` command, so you can use

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\begin{center}}{\begin{center}\vspace*{1in}}{}{}
```

in the preamble of your `.tex` document. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{uiucecethesis09}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\begin{center}}{\begin{center}\vspace*{1in}}{}{}

\msthesis

\title{Title Goes Here and Will Be Automatically Set in ALL CAPS}
\author{Your Name Goes Here}
\department{Electrical and Computer Engineering}
\degreeyear{year}

\advisor{Your Adviser Here}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect Gonzalo! Thanks for being such a sport and going through the actual cls document :)